# Wait for all processes with a certain name to finish (in bash)

Tags: bash, ubuntu, wait, pid

I would like to `wait` in linux (Ubuntu 11.10) for a load of processes to finish. Each of these processes has a different pid but the same name. Is it possible to do this?

EDIT:

Perhaps I should specify that I don't necessarily know what the pid are, just the process name.

EDIT:

Thanks for the answers; Kevin's seems to do what I want. However, it doesn't work in the specific application I have, so I've posted a more detailed follow-up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040417/parrallel-processing-in-shell-scripting-pid-is-not-a-child-of-this-shell).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
wait $(pgrep programName)
```

Ought to do it.

Comment: Provided that no new ones spawn after the `pgrep` executes.

Comment: That requires that the process you want to wait for was started in the same shell you want to use the wait command in.

Answer (score 3):

```
wait $(pidof processname)
```

perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have the pid of these processes:

```
wait $pid_of_process
```

That should do it.