# Parallel processing in shell scripting, 'pid is not a child of this shell'

Tags: bash, shell, parallel-processing, wait

I have a question about parallel processing in shell scripting. I have a program `my
Program`, which I wish to run multiple times, in a loop within a loop. This program is basically this:

```
MYPATHDIR=`ls $MYPATH`
for SUBDIRS in $MYPATHDIR; do
  SUBDIR_FILES=`ls $MYPATH/$SUBDIRS`
  for SUBSUBDIRS in $SUBDIR_FILES; do
    find $MYPATH/$SUBDIRS/$SUBSUBDIRS | ./myProgram $MYPATH/$SUBDIRS/outputfile.dat
  done
done
```

What I wish to do is to take advantage of parallel processing. So I tried this for the middle line to start all the `myPrograms` at once:

```
(find $MYPATH/$SUBDIRS/$SUBSUBDIRS | ./myProgram $MYPATH/$SUBDIRS/outputfile.dat &)
```

However, this began all 300 or so calls to `myProgram` simultaneously, causing RAM issues etc.

What I would like to do is to run each occurrence of `myProgram` in the inner loop in parallel, but wait for all of these to finish before moving on to the next outer loop iteration. Based on the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038723/wait-for-all-processes-with-a-certain-name-to-finish-in-bash), I tried the following:

```
for SUBDIRS in $MYPATHDIR; do
  SUBDIR_FILES=`ls $MYPATH/$SUBDIRS`
  for SUBSUBDIRS in $SUBDIR_FILES; do
    (find $MYPATH/$SUBDIRS/$SUBSUBDIRS | ./myProgram $MYPATH/$SUBDIRS/outputfile.dat &)
  done
  wait $(pgrep myProgram)   
done
```

But I got the following warning/error, repeated multiple times:

```
./myScript.sh: line 30: wait: pid 1133 is not a child of this shell
```

...and all the `myPrograms` were started at once, as before.

What am I doing wrong? What can I do to achieve my aims? Thanks.

Comment: `()` invokes a subshell, which then invokes find/myprogram, so you're dealing with "grandchildren" processes. You can't wait on grandchildren, only direct descendants (aka children).

Comment: I see. Can I alter my code to make them children instead of grandchildren?

Comment: Right I've taken out the brackets and it seems to be working. Megaparty, post your comment as an answer and you're in the money.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`()` invokes a subshell, which then invokes find/myprogram, so you're dealing with "grandchildren" processes. You can't wait on grandchildren, only direct descendants (aka children).

Answer (score 1):

You may find [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/s/parallel/) useful.

```
parallel -j+0 ./myProgram ::: $MYPATH/$SUBDIRS/*
```

This will run as many as `./myProgram` as CPU cores in parallel.